# GeForce GTX1050Ti Driver Installation Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I am trying to install my drivers

I have a GeForce GTX1050Ti, but when I use the GeForce experience downloaded from this page: https://www.geforce.com/drivers .. This happens:
[image]

It says that the NVIDIA Graphic Controller is not compatible with my Windows Version .. I have Windows 10 Pro 64 bits, so it makes no sense to me that is not compatible

[image]

My Windows Version is:

[image]

The version of the driver is:
GeForce_Experience_v3.20.1.57

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says that the NVIDIA Graphic Controller is not compatible with my Windows Version .. I have Windows 10 Pro 64 bits, so it makes no sense to me that is not compatible

**The Nvidia driver you are attempting to install is unsupported on the 1507(10240).**

`Windows 10 version 1507` has not been supported for more than 2 years.  There is absolutely no way a `GeForce GTX 1050 Ti` driver can be installed on the version of Windows 10 you have installed.

**You need to update your Windows 10 system to a supported version of Windows 10.**  There are only three versions currently supported.  `Windows 10 version 1809`, `Windows 10 version 1903`, and `Windows 10 version 1909`.

Due to the fact you are running 1507, you will likely have difficulty, migrating directly to one of those versions.  Which means you will have to download ISOs for the previous versions, upgrade to those versions manually, until Windows 10 is able to successfully be upgraded to 1809, 1903, or 1909.

**There are absolutely no other solutions to your problem.  `Windows 10 version 1507` has not been supported by Microsoft nearly 2 years.

Comment: are you sure? because I remember installing it some time before .. How do you know that much?

Comment: This is wrong. Don't update if you don't want to!!! See my answer.

Comment: My answer is absolutely 100% correct.

Answer (score -2):

Download an old version of the graphics driver.

Ramhound was for some reason talking about 1080 Ti when you said 1050 Ti.

GTX 1050 Ti was released in Oct 2016. 
Therefore you had about 5 months of driver updates compatible with your version of windows.

So my advice would just be to find an older driver online released between Oct. 25 2016 and Mar 10 2017. You don't have to update. I sure wouldn't want to. :)

Update: Go here https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx to get old versions of the driver straight from nvidia's website. As you can see in the screenshot, there's multiple versions from the time period necessary. Make sure to select the exact same selections I've made on my screenshot, then download one of the ones from within the time period.

[image: Nvidia old version driver]

Comment: So what versions of the Nvidia driver specifically support  *Windows 10 version 1507*?  Where can the author get that driver?  The current Nvidia driver doesn’t support 1507, the versions on the Nvidia website, do not support it.  Author needs safe solutions to their problem that will result in a signed Nvidia display driver.

Comment: Updated to include the links from nvidia website. Do you know why I was downvoted? Is it because i didn't include the safe download link or because the people who downvoted don't believe in not updating? Updating kills your PC/phone etc over time, because the updates are built for the newest and best hardware. If you constantly update you'll be left with slow, buggy or sometimes bootlooped devices after years, whereas keeping the same version keeps it mostly running at the same fast speed as when you built or acquired your PC/device.

Comment: @JackarySmith Can't speak for why people downvoted, but not updating software, *especially* your OS, is a MASSIVE mistake, *especially* on Windows. That is how you get viruses/malware/etc. I don't think the OP's current version even has the Spectre/Meltdown patch, which would mean since they're on a 7th Gen Intel CPU, anyone in the world could access *everything their CPU processes*. That is why you *always* stay *at least* a version or two within the current version.

Comment: Oh well that's true, if the PC owner isn't a guy with a lot of knowledge on how to prevent viruses, I guess I would have to tell them to update as well. It's just that I've had so much experience with updates destroying my devices in various ways that I do everything possible not to let them update anymore. That even includes my surface pro (the device created FOR Windows 10) bootlooping multiple times after multiple different updates. I know I have a pretty safe handle on viruses, but... I can definitely agree that it's better for people with less knowledge on this to update.

Comment: I had actually originally thought that the OP had the same mindset, because if he didn't set auto updates off on purpose with lots of research on how to do it, then I have no idea how his PC isn't already auto updated.

Comment: @JackarySmith - Yes;  I personally downvoted your answer due the lack of details, with regards to how the author could find, a safe reliable copy of a outdated Nvidia driver.  I mean your screenshot clearly indicates that isn't going to be from Nvidia, which is exactly, what I specified in my answer.  Spectre and Meltdown mitigation were released for all versions of Windows 10.  Future versions of Windows 10 automatically included them.  *The screenshot from Nvidia indicates no drivers before Feb 2019 can be downloaded from Nvidia.*

Comment: @Ramhound - oh whoops haha, i did not even realize that the website had the year of 2019 on it. Welp, I give up. There's obviously other websites to download it from but I'm not going to give one not from Nvidia since the people here (you) seem to be really against that.